# EF migrations - seed only executes when attached to debugger

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-4.1

I am using Entity Framework (4.3) migrations. I have a config class as normal that defines a Seed method, which is supposed to called after the migrations to add the data:

```
internal sealed class SettingsConfig : DbMigrationsConfiguration<My.Assembly>
{
    public SettingsConfig()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = false;
    }

    protected override void Seed(ScannerAreaManager.DataAccess.CableSenseLocal context)
    {
        //  This method will be called after migrating to the latest version.
    }
}
```

I'm running SQL Server profiler to see what's happening to the database.

Now, if I delete the database, and run this application from Visual studio with F5 (attached to debugger), it runs, and I can see the database gets created, migrations run, and the seed method being called and adding data to the database

If I then delete my database, and run the application again with Ctrl-F5 (NOT attached to the debugger), then I see my database gets created, the migrations run, **but the seed method never gets called.**

Surely this isn't by design? Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My bad, this was caused by our code attempting to read from the context before it had been initialised - but only when not run in debug mode.

EF does indeed behave as expected - the seed method gets called after the migrations have executed.